# Export and download a Google Spreadsheet using Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm having a hard time implementing a script using Google Script to export and download a spreadsheet. First, I create the spreadsheet using the Google Drive API, which is completed successfully. Then I'm trying to export the spreadsheet to a Microsoft Excel document and download it using the Google Drive API. I've tried the HTTP request (link below) and also calling the method **export** from the API. The best I've got is a 200 response from the HTTP request but no download at all. I ran out of ideas and tests.

Please, any suggestion or solution will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[SpreadsheetId]/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&alt=media&key=[MY_CLIENT_ID]

```
Drive.Files.export(spreadsheetId, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', {"alt":"media","client_secret":[client_secret_key]});
```

Comment: About `Then I'm trying to export the spreadsheet to a Microsoft Excel document and download it using the Google Drive API.`, where do you want to download it to?

Comment: About Tanaike question, I want to download it to my computer -local Downloads folder-. My browser is Google Chrome, OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37212135/7108653

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Tanaike. That thread did help me. Several days struggling with that issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.