# Google Apps Script To Download File From URL in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet set up where each row contains several URLs. Clicking these URLs downloads the contents to my local Downloads folder where I can then organize the contents. I want to be able to automate clicking URLs for a row that I select to download the link contents.

The function I am using is below.

```
function downloadLinks(currentRow) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Identify the range where the URLs exist based on the row selected.
  // Save to rangeValues list.
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1, 1, 26);
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

  // For each rangeValue[0][4] to [0][23], use getUI to open up link.
  // Qualify each value before downloading by ensuring it is a URL.
  // Pause 2.5s after each download to allow time for downloading.
  for (j = 4; j < 24; j++) {
    if (rangeValues[0][j].includes("https")) {
      var html = "<script>window.location.assign('" + rangeValues[0][j] + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
      var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Sending link contents to Downloads folder');
      Utilities.sleep(2500);
    }
  }
}
```

When I first wrote this a couple months back, the function would take each URL and open them in a new tab and then promptly download the link contents.

NOW, the function takes each URL and opens them up in a new tab, but does not download anything.

I have attempted researching other parameters I can use with the window.open() method such as opening in a new window/opening in self, etc. I've also tried to use the openLink method with Google Scripts and that doesn't appear to be the answer either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is there any message in the web browser console? Are the files publicly available  (could be downloaded by anyone in the web)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [After Chrome version 83 release, file download in modal dialog doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62127708/1595451)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](How do I ask a good question?)

Comment: @Rubén - this is exactly the issue i was seeing! thanks for pointing me to the right thread.