# Button as a link on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with my google sheet. I had been using a script to go to a export-to-PDF link and then download the PDF file automatically when I press a button.

However, since a couple of weeks ago this thing is not working as before. Now, it opens a new tab in my google chrome but it doesn't download the PDF automatically but the address is correct.

I was wondering if Google Chrome changed something to avoid this to happen for security reasons. But anyway, I would like to be able to do it again.

My code is:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url_base+url_ext+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to download automatically. <a href="'+url_base+url_ext+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Creating PDF ..." );
```

Since I'm having this problem, I was also wondering if I can have a function to directly go to the link:

url_base+url_ext without the html thing just to download the PDF.

[image]
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qupWcQMBEoA-o4oAaM4ElldBKcQapshtO45vXtvMPa4/edit?usp=sharing

I would appreciate any help on this.

Regards,
Marco

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Chrome version 83 release, file download in modal dialog doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127708/after-chrome-version-83-release-file-download-in-modal-dialog-doesnt-work). Please, note that this is an automated message generated on behalf of users that suggest to the communty that the question is likely to have an answer elsewhere. This one is pretty common since the Chrome 83 release - the change is intentional, albeit breaking

Comment: I wonder why the automated message didn't just mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Cooper - as far as I recall, dupes are put into close review queue, are they not? At least I don't have the "dupehammer" yet (as well as close vote), so my flagging just waits to be reviewed

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How can I achieve this now?

Comment: Basically, you can't. There is a link to the issue tracker, there are a couple workarounds posted, but apart from that - you can only wait. You can ask your users to right-click and save manually, but that's it

Comment: Thank you so much!