# Create CSV files for specific sheets, then send email with table (files names & links)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Anyone who can bring some light on the following that I've been working on it the whole week, I'm almost there, I have only one or two issues. Firstly, the formatting of the table in the email, as you can see, in the attached screenshot, it's not aligned properly, and `No` goes up to 6 while it's supposed to stop at 3, likewise I couldn't get to display the border. Secondly, I don't know if I took the right approach to push the arrays of files names & links in order to create a new array (of arrays) using `var vA = [attachment, filenames]`, is it the right approach in order to use it in the table?
Finally, Is it possible to re-use the html body of the email to `showModalDialog` so that the user knows that the operation is done and can access the files straightway if they want to within the dialogue box?

**Email received at the moment:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
function test(){
  
  // Create CSV files for these Sample Sheets Names
  var mySheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
  var attachment = [];
  var filenames = [];
  var folder = "ID HERE";
  for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var name = sheet.getName();
    
    // will create a csv file for Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 only and ignore the other sheets
    if (mySheets.indexOf(name) !== -1) {

      // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
      fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
      
      // convert all available sheet data to csv format
      var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
      
      // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
      var url = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).createFile(fileName, csvFile).getId();
      
      attachment.push("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + url);
      filenames.push(fileName);
       }
  }      
  // I'm trying to create an array of arrays (files names & respective links)
      var vA = [attachment, filenames]
  
  Logger.log(vA);
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject="Test CSV for specific sheets";
  // Got inspired by Cooper's answers for this:
  var html='<style>th,td{border:2px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>No</th><th>Link</th><th>Class</th>';
  var item = 1;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    html+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(i==0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('%s<td><a href="%s">Link</a></tr></td>',item++,vA[i][j]);
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('%s</tr><tr><td><th><td>%s</tr></td>',item++,vA[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
      GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,'',{htmlBody: html});
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet){
  // some code here
}
```

Ideally I'm trying to send an email with the following format, or something similar:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this was a good idea`var vA = [attachment, filenames]` I think I'd prefer to use and array of objects. `vA[i]={attachment:'',filename:''}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the HTML body as the table of the bottom image shown in your question using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I would like to propose to modify your HTML.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var html='<style>th,td{border:2px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>No</th><th>Link</th><th>Class</th>';
var item = 1;
for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
  html+='<tr>';
  for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
    if(i==0) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('%s<td><a href="%s">Link</a></tr></td>',item++,vA[i][j]);
    }else{
      html+=Utilities.formatString('%s</tr><tr><td><th><td>%s</tr></td>',item++,vA[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
html+='</table>';
```

To:

```
var html = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; width: 500px"><thead><tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">No</font></th><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">File name</font></th><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">Link</font></th></tr></thead><tbody>';
filenames.forEach((e, i) => html += `<tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><td style="border: 2px solid black">${i + 1}<\/td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black">${e}<\/td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><a href="${attachment[i]}">Link<\/a><\/td><\/tr>`);
html += '</tbody></table>';
```

#### Result:

When above modified script is used, the following HTML body is created. In this case, the sample URL is used.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; width: 500px"><thead><tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">No</font></th><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">File name</font></th><th style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black; background-color: #008000;"><font color="#FFFFFF">Link</font></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><td style="border: 2px solid black">1</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black">Sheet1.csv</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=sample">Link</a></td></tr><tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><td style="border: 2px solid black">2</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black">Sheet2.csv</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=sample">Link</a></td></tr><tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><td style="border: 2px solid black">3</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black">Sheet3.csv</td><td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid black"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=sample">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've replaced in my code with your suggestion, I get an error for this line `filenames.forEach((e, i) = .......`  (**Syntax error**) is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About the error message, I thought that you might be using the script without V8 runtime. When you use the script without V8, please enable V8 runtime at the script editor and try it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought it was enabled by default in my projects. I've enabled it now, and it's seems working as wanted. Can you give me any hint regarding this:  in my question I run the script on  var mySheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];, but in reality I collect the sheets names with a sidebar that I've already created, and where the user can select which sheet they want to export as CSV. **My question**: when the user click on submit, how can I show a spinner inside the sidebar so the user understands that the task has started?

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: thank you a lot for your continuous and tremendous support. I will try to research first and see what I can do. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for your response. When you post the new question, I would like to check it and think of the solution.

Comment: Please allow me one more question related to my original post where I've mentioned the need to display a `dialog box`. I was able to show the dialog box in the spreadsheet, with the table containing the files names and inks after the mail is sent. **Problem**: when clicking on the link it doesn't start the download if I'm using the Chrome browser, but if I use Firefox, the download start. Is it a browser issue?

Comment: @Nabnub I think that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157740 But the issue of your comment is new issue. So if that thread was not useful and you need more information for it, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.