# Google script - link to download /export file from google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, download, export

on google sites i have a search page and i need to insert a button to export to a spreadsheet the search. The script creates a spreadsheet with the information and provides a download link.

- How can I do this without reloading the search page?
- is it possible to open a modal or a window over the page to display the link?
- how can I fill in the `doGet()` event argument from the search page?

In another implementation, I had a problem with the sandbox, saying that downloading was disabled in chrome since update 83. is there any way to solve this?

Or if anyone has another solution for all of that, it would be most welcome. I appreciate the collaboration.

my code.gs:

```
  function doGet(e)
  {
    var report = e.parameter.report; //// how to fill a 'parameter' in search.html ?
  
    if(report) 
    {
      var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.create('asd');
      // fill the Spreadsheet
      var ssID = planilha.getId();
      var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ssID+'/export?format=xlsx';
      return ?? /// returns what exactly?
    }
    
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('search').evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Chrome version 83 release, file download in modal dialog doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127708/after-chrome-version-83-release-file-download-in-modal-dialog-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a reported issue on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720) to to add `"allow-downloads"` in `HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL`

You can go there and click on the star besides the issue title so it gets more visibility.

Comment: Kessy, thanks for the information! I will follow the issue. But the other questions remain.

Comment: @MarcoPires can you share the code for the full web app embedded on sites, and how do you have the search bar? More details on your implementation basically, avoid providing personal information such as Id's