# Google Sheets script - extend selection from active worksheet to selected worskheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a custom script that converts the google spreadsheet from the active worksheet to an xlsx format and downloads it to xlsx.

Is there a way to do this with the selected worksheets not just the active worksheet.

Can anyone help with this?

**Here is my code:**

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('ACTION')
      .addItem('Download as XLSX', 'downloadXLS_GUI')
      .addToUi();
}


/**
 * Display a modal dialog with a single download link.
 *
 * From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336778/1677912
 */
function downloadXLS_GUI() {
  // Get active spreadsheet and active sheet
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get data from columns A to Q
  var data = selectedSheet.getRange("A:Q").getValues();
  
  // Create a new spreadsheet to store the data
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(activeSheet.getName() + '_DownloadedData');
  
  // Set the values in the new spreadsheet
  newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  
  // Get the new spreadsheet ID
  var newSpreadsheetId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  
  // Generate download URL for the new spreadsheet
  var downloadURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + newSpreadsheetId + '/export?format=xlsx';
  
  // Display a modal dialog box with download link
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                  .createHtmlOutput('<a href="' + downloadURL + '" download="' + activeSheet.getName() + '.xlsx">Click to download</a>')
                  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                  .setWidth(80)
                  .setHeight(60);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Download XLS');
  
  // Close the new spreadsheet without saving changes
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you share how `selectedSheet` is defined in your code? Also, you should be able to use `selected worksheets not just the active worksheet`, with [`getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).

Comment: Just get the sheet by name. Look in Range class for getSheetByName() method

Answer (score 1):

Just use the method getSheetByName() and you can get any sheet in the spreadsheet

```
function downloadXLS_GUI() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var vs = sh.getRange("A1:Q" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.create(sh.getName() + '_DownloadedData');
  ss1.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  var downloadURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ss1.getId(); + '/export?format=xlsx';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<a href="' + downloadURL + '" download="' + sh.getName() + '.xlsx">Click to download</a>')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(80)
    .setHeight(60);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Download XLS');
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss1.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

In this scenario the new sheet will be name Sheet1 because all spreadsheets are created with a Sheet1. So the active sheet will be the only sheet.

When you use the term Sheet on this site you should mean an object of the type - [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)