# How to download a file with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create and download a spreadhsheet with google apps script. I create a file

`const newDocument = SpreadsheetApp.create("docname");`

how can I download the file in xlsx or csv formatting to my machine ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does placing the document in drive and let it sync to your machine work for you?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat no ( I need to download the file I create in script. Maybe there is a way to open a download url or something ?

Comment: @NanePetrosyan you need to produce an event in order to download the file from the browser. You can't just download it. You need to click somewhere and do it. Here is a [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460815/11225291) example on how to do that. And [here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/11/23/downloading-active-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet-as-csv-and-pdf-file-by-clicking-button/) is another alternative to create a sidebar with 2 buttons that will allow you to download the file.

Comment: Check also this question which is very close to what you want. [Initiate a download from google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script)