# How to randomly download many files from a google drive folder

Tags: download, google-drive-api

I looked answers from this question [Download file from Google Drive to local folder from Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376102/download-file-from-google-drive-to-local-folder-from-google-apps-script)

The answers to above questions only give instructions to download a single file or folder, But I want to download a small no.(say 50) of random files from a folder, Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] have you tried please show us by editing your question and adding an [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest by starting with [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to return the first 100 files on your google drive account, you can then loop through them and download each of them one at a time.    The file.list method has an option called [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) which would allow you to search for only files with in a directory using parents.

yes all of this can be done programmatically